# Why am I missing form submit trigger in Google Scripts UI?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-forms

In Google Scripts I'm trying to use a **on form submit** trigger, but all I see in events are Time-Driven and From Calendar[image]

Answer (score 0):

The project must be [bound](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) to the Google form or to the connected spreadsheet for the `onFormSubmit` trigger to be available in the triggers UI.

- Open your Google form
- Click Tools > Script editor from within the form